# Cancel a user edit from property set in the ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

quite a newbie question, i'm sure, but i wasn't able to find an answer...
I have a control (in this case- a combo box) which is bound to a ViewModel property:

```
<ComboBox 
      x:Name="methodTypeCmb"
      Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllNames, Mode=OneTime}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, Mode=TwoWay}"
      Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}"
      />
```

In my ViewModel, when this property changes, I want to ask the user to confirm the change.
If the user clicks 'no', I want to cancel the change.
However, I must be doing something wrong, because my view doesn't revert back to the previous value when the change is cancelled.

The ViewModel's property:

```
public string Name
{
    get { return m_model.Name; }
    set
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you absolutely sure?","Change ",MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            // change name
        }
        base.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
    }
}
```

Comment: What exact control are you using, and what editable property are you binding to meaning how exactly is the user setting the value from the UI?

Comment: I'm using a combobox. I'll give your code snippet a try and will let you know. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because you are cancelling within the scope of the text changing event, wpf ignores the property changed event.  You must call it from the dispatcher

```
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart)delegate
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        });
```

You should leave your existing "OnPropertyChanged("Name");" at the bottom of the function just add the above line to the block where you are cancelling

EDIT:  The following code works I have tested it

```
        public string Newtext
        {
            get
            {
                return this._newtext;
            }
            set
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Apply?", "", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                {
                    this._newtext = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("Newtext"); //Ignored
                }
                else
                {
                    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke((ThreadStart)delegate
                    {
                        OnPropertyChanged("Newtext");
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: used `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`. didn't work. But I think you're on the right track with the idea of changing within the change event

Comment: Works fine on my end, posted a functioning snippet of a test accessor I used on a viewmodel.  Apologies for the "CurrentDispatcher" omission, must have copied the wrong snippet.

Comment: I was using a TextBox to test and it would seem that the behavior is not the same for all controls, see above comment on question.

Comment: for my combobox it gives strange behaviour after the first time it's invoked (i.e not updating the bound property correctly). strange..